# Email notifications sent by Drupal have broken links sometimes

Tags: email, drupal

I'm using the Subscriptions module of Drupal to send out subscribed emails on a regular basis and I've noticed that the links embedded in the email will break if the link is too long, but only for some users. The email client that user is using is Entourage. The crazy thing is that I use Entourage, also, but I don't have that problem with the links in my subscription emails that are sent to me. Here's what's happening:

http:samplelinkhere?var=blahblah
blahblah

The top line of the link will be underlined and part of the link, but the bottom part will not be underlined (even though it should be) and so, the link is broken. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is not much you can do about this. As long as the links do not contain line breaks in the original mails sent by your server, it is up to the receivers mail client to add line breaks for readability, usually based on some user preference settings (Which could explain the difference to your own Entourage client).

Also, some clients try to detect links and avoid breaking them, others don't, and some even have plugins for this.

A possible workaround would be sending HTML mails instead, but that opens a huge different can of worms concerning mail client compatibility, so I do not recommend it.

Comment: I was thinking this to be the case, but I figured I'd ask just to see if someone could tell me otherwise. Is there a way to use a url shortener on the fly and shorten the url as the email is getting generated so that this is never an issue? Also, any idea about what that preference in entourage might be? Thanks.

Comment: I have not used one so far, but would expect most URL shortener services to offer an automation API that you can use 'on the fly'. Though I have to say that I would be skeptical about using tiny URLs in emails, as they effectively disguise the link, since the user will have no clue where he'll end up.

Comment: As for the preferences in Entourage, I do not use it, so I don't know, but would expect it to be under something like 'read' or 'display' settings.